# Jquery not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I think i may be almost there (thanks to the help of a few others) but still cant seem to get my tweets to show one at a time in a loop

```
var $container = $('#innerTwitter');

$.get('/feed', function (data) {
    showTweets($(data).slice(0, 5))
}, 'json');

function showTweets(tweets) {
    var tweetPs = $.map(tweets, function (t) {
        return $('<p></p>').text(t.text).hide();
    });

    $container.append(tweetPs);
    tweetPs[0].show();

    var currentIndex = 0;

    var nextTweet = function () {
        var nextIndex = currentIndex == tweetPs.length - 1 ? 0 : currentIndex + 1;
        tweetPs[currentIndex].fadeOut(400, function () {
            tweetPs[nextIndex].fadeIn(400);
        });
        currentIndex = nextIndex;
    };

    setInterval(nextTweet, 2000);
}
```

Within my console (Chrome) I get this error

```
Uncaught Error: NotFoundError: DOM Exception 8
```

can anyone see anything that I am doing wrong

Any help appreciated

Comment: Where do you get the error?

Comment: In the chrome console

Comment: What type of element is `$('#innerTwitter');`?

Comment: @epascarello just a div to put the P tags in

Comment: You're wrapping data in `$()`, which would suggest that it's HTML, and you then have a collection of elements, which you then pass to `$.map`, and inside `$.map` you do `t.text`? Isn't `t` now a native JS element, and does it have a `text` property?

Comment: unsure what you mean, yes its HTML, yes there are a collection of elements..Do you know what to amend, is t causing me a problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using jquery 1.7 (wich was an important statement since it doesnt show the same error). It is impossible to append an array (in most recent version, you can).

this line:

```
$container.append(tweetPs);
```

Is causing the error, try to loop through every element and append them individually :

```
$.each($tweetPs, function(){
    $container.append(this);
})
```

Comment: @Richlewis - This answer is wrong, `$.map` would create an array of jQuery objects, and doing `tweetPs[0]` would get the first jQuery object from the array, not the native JS element like it would in many other methods, `tweetPs[0].show()` is completely valid.

Comment: @Richlewis, Adeneo is right. Do you have any Development server? so we can see your error?

Comment: only on localhost at the moment sorry....this is full error Uncaught Error: NotFoundError: DOM Exception 8 jquery-1.7.min.js:4
f.extend.clean jquery-1.7.min.js:4
f.buildFragment jquery-1.7.min.js:4
f.fn.extend.domManip jquery-1.7.min.js:4
f.fn.extend.append jquery-1.7.min.js:3
showTweets localhost/:467
(anonymous function) localhost/:460
n jquery-1.7.min.js:2
o.fireWith jquery-1.7.min.js:2
w jquery-1.7.min.js:4
d

Comment: ah so upgrade jquery and amend my append

Comment: So is the answer to upgrade jquery and change the append as stated?

Comment: As you wish, having the lastest version of jquery isnt a bad thing.... But if you are lazy, copy the code.

Comment: ok jsut to update, it is now iterating through the tweets (as each tweet has a background image) and that is looping but no text being shown, so i now have a blank scroller ...almost there

Comment: @adeneo, my bad, i jsut assumed, and rich, your next problem is probly the t.text or somewhere close.

Comment: Try the map function in my deleted answer, I tested that four times, so it should work ;) ...

Comment: cant find deleted answer? is it this line causing an issue return $('<p></p>', {text: $(t).text()}).hide();

Comment: its ok got it working, thanks guys, all your help has been much appreciated